# send SMS using java spring mvc not working

Tags: java, spring-mvc, sms

I am working one web application spring MVC.i want to send sms using web.
I tried below code.
If i run single java file using main() then its working and when i tried it through web its not working.

Can anybody help me to solve this.
Below is my code

```
   public static String doSendSMS(String url_str) {
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
    try {
        URL obj = new URL(url_str);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        // optional default is GET
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url_str);
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return response.toString();
}
```

Comment: it might help if you log the exception in the catch block.

Comment: there is no any error

Comment: Do you have permissions to make HTTP calls from the server on which you are running it? If no exception in the catch, can you try logging to complete request and response from the service to see what is happening.

Comment: Please share the error you are receiving on doing so.

Comment: there is no error.but after searching i change my code and its working now.

Answer (score 0):

Below is working code.

```
 public class sms {
    private static String sessionCookie;
    public static String loginSMS(String userName, String password,String url) {
    String cookie = null;
    URL urlLogin;
    String loginContent;
    HttpURLConnection loginConnection;

    try {
        //UTF-8 encoding is the web standard so data must be encoded to UTF-8
        userName = URLEncoder.encode(userName, "UTF-8");
        password = URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8");
        urlLogin = new URL(url);
        loginConnection = (HttpURLConnection) urlLogin.openConnection();
        loginContent = "username=" + userName + "&password=" + password;
        loginConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        loginConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.0.5) Gecko/2008120122 Firefox/3.0.5");
        loginConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(loginContent.length()));
        loginConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        loginConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "*/*");
        loginConnection.setRequestProperty("Referer", url);
        loginConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        loginConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
        //Writing the Content to the site
        PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(loginConnection.getOutputStream()), true);
        printWriter.print(loginContent);
        printWriter.flush();
        printWriter.close();
        //Reading the cookie
        cookie = loginConnection.getHeaderField("Set-Cookie");
    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        System.err.println("Login URL Error");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
        System.err.println("Error in encoding Username or Password");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.err.println("Can not connect to Login URL");
    }
    if (cookie == null || cookie.isEmpty()) {
        System.err.println("Some error occured...Try again in a few seconds..If still problem exists check your username and password");
    }
    sessionCookie = cookie;
    return cookie;

}

public static void sendSMS( String action,String urlString,String content) {
    loginSMS("user", "user123","url");
    URL sendURL;
    HttpURLConnection sendConnection;
    String sendContent;
    try {
        sendURL = new URL(urlString);
        sendConnection = (HttpURLConnection) sendURL.openConnection();
        // sendContent="custid=undefined&HiddenAction=instantsms&Action="+action+"&login=&pass=&MobNo="+ phoneNumber+ "&textArea="+message;
        sendContent = content;
        sendConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        sendConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.0.5) Gecko/2008120122 Firefox/3.0.5");
        sendConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(sendContent.getBytes().length));
        sendConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        sendConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "*/*");
        sendConnection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", sessionCookie);
        sendConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        sendConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);

        PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(sendConnection.getOutputStream()), true);
        printWriter.print(sendContent);
        printWriter.flush();
        printWriter.close();
        //Reading the returned web page to analyse whether the operation was sucessfull
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sendConnection.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder SendResult = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            SendResult.append(line);
            SendResult.append('\n');
            //Message has been submitted successfully
        }
        System.out.println("Responce : " + SendResult);
        bufferedReader.close();
        logoutSMS();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
        System.err.println("Message content encoding error");
        //  System.exit(0);
    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        System.err.println("Sending URL Error");
        //   System.exit(0);
    } catch (IOException ex) {

        System.err.println("Sending URL Connection Error");
        ex.printStackTrace();
        //  System.exit(0);
    }

}
}
```